# How can I pass variables to docker when I build a container with Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build a container with a PHP project that has a DDBB connection, and I'm looking to set the DDBB through environment variables.

I have defined the variables with pipeline variables.

[image: variables]

I also set the variables in the variable sections

```
variables:
  imageName: 'project'
  repositoryNameDes: 'portalweb-des/project'
  repositoryNamePro: 'portalweb-pro/project'
  connectionECRpredes: 'amazon container registry w-predes'
  connectionECRpro: 'amazon container registry w-pro'
  tName: $(Build.SourceBranchName)_$(Build.SourceVersion)
  ecrRepositoryNameBaseUrl: '513537361685.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
  dirNameS3: 'project'
  bucketNameDes: 'cluster-drupal-des-deploy-s3'
  deployOnECS: $[or(startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/tags/'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feature/generardocker'))]
  ddbb_name: $(DDBB_NAME)
```

But I'm not able to see how to load the variables when I make the build, I'm not sure if there is an option so set enviroment variables, if I have to write a custom build to run with the variable or how to make it.

```
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build an image
  inputs:
    repository: $(imageName)
    command: build
    Dockerfile: Dockerfile
    tags: $(tName)
- task: ECRPushImage@1
  inputs:
    ENV: '$(dev)'
    awsCredentials: '$(connectionECRpredes)'
    regionName: 'eu-west-1'
    imageSource: 'imagename'
    sourceImageName: '$(imageName)'
    sourceImageTag: '$(tName)'
    repositoryName: '$(repositoryNameDes)'
    pushTag: $(tName)
```

Comment: Did you get any error during build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most common case, you set the variables and use them within the YAML file. This allows you to track changes to the variable in your version control system. You can also define variables in the pipeline settings UI (see the Classic tab) and reference them in your YAML.

Here's an example that shows how to set two variables, `configuration` and `platform`, and use them later in steps. To use a variable in a YAML statement, wrap it in `$()`.

```
# Set variables once
variables:
  configuration: debug
  platform: x64

steps:

# Use them once
- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: solution1.sln
    configuration: $(configuration) # Use the variable
    platform: $(platform)

# Use them again
- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: solution2.sln
    configuration: $(configuration) # Use the variable
    platform: $(platform)
```

You could check the following link for more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch